# I want the last row of all players in a specific month+year

Tags: php, sql, join, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

Here is a simplified version of my sql table of 2 months (ORDERED BY DATE):

> player_id |
>   date            |
>   score 
>   1               2011-05-25
>     1200 
>   2               2011-05-25
>     3400 
>   3               2011-05-26
>     3200 
>   4               2011-05-26
>     4400 
>   **1               2011-05-28
>     1000 
>
>   2               2011-05-28
>     2000 
>
>   3               2011-05-29
>     3000 
>
>   4               2011-05-29
>     4000** 
>   1               2011-06-24
>     1300 
>   2               2011-06-24
>     2500 
>   3               2011-06-24
>     5000 
>   4               2011-06-24
>     3000

Basically, I want a query that shows the last score of all players in a specific month/specific year.

Example:

> If I want the final scores of all players in the month 05, te result
>   would be: 
>   1    2011-05-28    1000 
>   2    2011-05-28    2000 
>   3    2011-05-29    3000 
>   4    2011-05-29    4000

My sql query so far:

```
  SELECT m1.* FROM table m1 
    LEFT JOIN table m2 ON (m1.player_id = m2.player_id AND m1.date < m2.date) 
    WHERE m2.date IS NULL 
    AND month(m1.date) = 05 
    AND year(m1.date) = 2011 
    ORDER BY score DESC);
```

This doesn't seem to show all players, only players that didn't play in the months after 05. Where do I add the date select?

**EDIT
John Nestoriak's answer bellow did the trick for me :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what are the 2 tables that you're `JOIN`-ing? You explained only 1 table.

Comment: @cha0site he is joining the table on itself. And I think you might just need to change your `<` in the join to `>`. Trying to remember, but I believe you want the max from the first table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think he's referring to the technique shown here: [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

With the additional constraint of he doesn't want the last record but the last record in a given month.

Oddly enough you have to give that additional constraint twice, once in the join condition and again to filter the results. This should do it for you.

```
SELECT m1.* FROM table m1 
  LEFT JOIN table m2 ON 
    (m1.player_id = m2.player_id AND m1.date < m2.date 
     AND m2.date < '2011-06-01') 
  WHERE m2.date IS NULL AND month(m1.date) = 5 AND year(m1.date) = 2011
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `(player_id, date)` combination in Unique:

```
SELECT 
      t.*
FROM 
      TableX AS t
  JOIN
      ( SELECT 
              player_id
            , MAX(date) AS maxDate
        FROM
            TableX
        WHERE 
             date BETWEEN '2011-05-01'
                      AND LAST_DAY('2011-05-01')
        GROUP BY
              player_id
      ) AS tg
    ON  
      (tg.player_id, tg.maxDate) = (t.player_id, t.date)
ORDER BY 
      t.score DESC
```